# How to join multiple selects in a stored procedure with MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, join

I have a database with dynamically generated tables. I'm writting a stored procedure to execute queries over the generated tables and I need to see the results in the query analyzer tool (or alike).

What I currently have is:

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname

DECLARE TableNameCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT TableName FROM [xxxTables] WHERE xxx...

OPEN TableNameCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableNameCursor INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Query nvarchar
    SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName
    EXEC sp_executesql @Query

    -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
    FETCH NEXT FROM TableNameCursor INTO @TableName
END
```

But as I have multiple selects I'm not getting the output. How can I fix the stored procedure to show the result?

All the tables have the same layout so I can join them.

Comment: *‘All the tables have the same layout so I can join them.’* – did you actually mean ***UNION** them*?

Comment: I mean that I can create the output as a single table

Comment: All right. Where exactly are you not getting the output (I mean, is it in the client application or in another stored procedure or...)? How is the SP invoked?

Comment: I calling the procedure directly on query analyzer and I'm not getting any output at all.

Comment: Oops, you did mention Query Analyzer in your question and I missed that, sorry. Perhaps, Query Analyzer does not support displaying multiple result sets returned by a single stored procedure. If the procedure does produce multiple results, I'm sure you would be able to see them if you ran the SP in an SSMS query window. I'm not sure, though, if you consider that tool to be *alike*.

Comment: Nope, executing the SP in SSMS also does not produce any output ... :?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless this is merely a typo produced when posting the script here, I might have finally found the issue. You haven't specified the maximum length for the `@Query` variable:

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar
```

In this context the maximum length defaults to `1`, as per [the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx):

> When *`n`* is not specified **in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1**. When *`n`* is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30.

When you are assigning a query string to `@Query`, it only stores the first character. Naturally, when you are later trying to execute the query, it returns nothing and should produce an error instead.

You can fix it by specifying a maximum length. In SQL Server 2005 or later version, it could be an explicit number (up to 4000) or `max`:

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)
```

In earlier versions `max` is not supported, so just use an explicit number:

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(4000)
```

Comment: Thanks! :) That was the issue, you saved my day ;)